# lenguaje C, debo utilizar el "strstr" para poder acceder a los datos de una estructura e imprimirlos, pero no puedo acceder al if, que esta mal?

Tags: c, string

este es el fragmento del codigo que me falla, no puedo acceder dentro del
`if`

```
printf("\nIngresa el nombre que desea buscar: ");
scanf("%s", NombrePersona);

if(strstr(NombrePersona, Registro.Nombre) == 1){
    printf("Calificacion 1: %d", Registro.Calificacion[0]);
}
```

creo que el problema es que el strstr no esta hecho bien

Answer (score 1):

`strstr`, de acuerdo con la [documentación](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/), te devuelve un puntero a la posición donde ha encontrado la subcadena ... luego comparar ese valor con `1` no te va a dar buenos resultados.

Vale, no sabes qué posición de memoria te va a devolver, así que no puedes usar ese valor en el `if`, pero por otro lado sabemos que `strstr` devuelve un puntero nulo cuando la subcadena no se ha encontrado. Ya lo tienes:

```
if (strstr(NombrePersona, Registro.Nombre) != NULL))
```